# Custom column names as arguments in the functions of stability R package

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, stability

I developed the `stability` R package which can be installed from CRAN.

```
install.packages("stability")
```

However, I have difficulty in making it to take custom column names as function arguments. Here is an example of `add_anova` function

```
library(stability)
data(ge_data)

YieldANOVA <-
  add_anova(
      .data = ge_data
    , .y    = Yield
    , .rep  = Rep
    , .gen  = Gen
    , .env  = Env
  )
YieldANOVA
```

The above code works fine. However, when I change the column names of the data.frame, it doesn't work as below:

```
df1 <- ge_data
names(df1) <- c("G", "Institute", "R", "Block", "E", "Y")

fm1 <-
  add_anova(
      .data = df1
    , .y    = Y
    , .rep  = Rep
    , .gen  = G
    , .env  = E
  )

Error in model.frame.default(formula = terms(.data$Y ~ .data$E + .data$Rep:.data$E +  : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable '.data$Rep'
```

Similarly another function `stab_reg`

```
fm1Reg <-
  stab_reg(
      .data = df1
    , .y    = Y
    , .gen  = G
    , .env  = E
  )

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Gen' not found
```

The codes of these functions can be accessed by

```
getAnywhere(add_anova.default)

function (.data, .y, .rep, .gen, .env) 
{
    Y <- enquo(.y)
    Rep <- enquo(.rep)
    G <- enquo(.gen)
    E <- enquo(.env)
    fm1 <- lm(formula = terms(.data$Y ~ .data$E + .data$Rep:.data$E + 
        .data$G + .data$G:.data$E, keep.order = TRUE), data = .data)
    fm1ANOVA <- anova(fm1)
    rownames(fm1ANOVA) <- c("Env", "Rep(Env)", "Gen", "Gen:Env", 
        "Residuals")
    fm1ANOVA[1, 4] <- fm1ANOVA[1, 3]/fm1ANOVA[2, 3]
    fm1ANOVA[2, 4] <- NA
    fm1ANOVA[1, 5] <- 1 - pf(as.numeric(fm1ANOVA[1, 4]), fm1ANOVA[1, 
        1], fm1ANOVA[2, 1])
    fm1ANOVA[2, 5] <- 1 - pf(as.numeric(fm1ANOVA[2, 4]), fm1ANOVA[2, 
        1], fm1ANOVA[5, 1])
    class(fm1ANOVA) <- c("anova", "data.frame")
    return(list(anova = fm1ANOVA))
}
<bytecode: 0xc327c28>
<environment: namespace:stability>
```

and

```
   getAnywhere(stab_reg.default)

function (.data, .y, .rep, .gen, .env) 
{
    Y <- enquo(.y)
    Rep <- enquo(.rep)
    G <- enquo(.gen)
    E <- enquo(.env)
    g <- length(levels(.data$G))
    e <- length(levels(.data$E))
    r <- length(levels(.data$Rep))
    g_means <- .data %>% dplyr::group_by(!!G) %>% dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(!!Y))
    names(g_means) <- c("G", "Mean")
    DataNew <- .data %>% dplyr::group_by(!!G, !!E) %>% dplyr::summarize(GEMean = mean(!!Y)) %>% 
        dplyr::group_by(!!E) %>% dplyr::mutate(EnvMean = mean(GEMean))
    IndvReg <- lme4::lmList(GEMean ~ EnvMean | Gen, data = DataNew)
    IndvRegFit <- summary(IndvReg)
    StabIndvReg <- tibble::as_tibble(data.frame(g_means, Slope = coef(IndvRegFit)[, 
        , 2][, 1], LCI = confint(IndvReg)[, , 2][, 1], UCI = confint(IndvReg)[, 
        , 2][, 2], R.Sqr = IndvRegFit$r.squared, RMSE = IndvRegFit$sigma, 
        SSE = IndvRegFit$sigma^2 * IndvRegFit$df[, 2], Delta = IndvRegFit$sigma^2 * 
            IndvRegFit$df[, 2]/r))
    MeanSlopePlot <- ggplot(data = StabIndvReg, mapping = aes(x = Slope, 
        y = Mean)) + geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label = G), 
        size = 2.5, vjust = 1.25, colour = "black") + geom_vline(xintercept = 1, 
        linetype = "dotdash") + geom_hline(yintercept = mean(StabIndvReg$Mean), 
        linetype = "dotdash") + labs(x = "Slope", y = "Mean") + 
        scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(), labels = scales::comma) + 
        scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(), labels = scales::comma) + 
        theme_bw()
    return(list(StabIndvReg = StabIndvReg, MeanSlopePlot = MeanSlopePlot))
}
<bytecode: 0xe431010>
<environment: namespace:stability>
```

Comment: @akrun: You helped me on the initial code of this problem.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problems in the data 'df1' is the column name is 'R' instead of "Rep" which was passed into the function.  Second, the terms passed into the formula are quosures.  we could change it to string with `quo_names` and then construct formula with `paste`

```
add_anova1 <- function (.data, .y, .rep, .gen, .env) {
    y1 <- quo_name(enquo(.y))
    r1 <- quo_name(enquo(.rep))
    g1 <- quo_name(enquo(.gen))
    e1 <- quo_name(enquo(.env))

    fm <- formula(paste0(y1, "~", paste(e1, paste(r1, e1, sep=":"), 
                  g1, paste(g1, e1, sep=":"), sep="+")))

    fm1 <- lm(terms(fm, keep.order = TRUE), data = .data)
    fm1ANOVA <- anova(fm1)
    rownames(fm1ANOVA) <- c("Env", "Rep(Env)", "Gen", "Gen:Env", 
        "Residuals")
    fm1ANOVA[1, 4] <- fm1ANOVA[1, 3]/fm1ANOVA[2, 3]
    fm1ANOVA[2, 4] <- NA
    fm1ANOVA[1, 5] <- 1 - pf(as.numeric(fm1ANOVA[1, 4]), fm1ANOVA[1, 
        1], fm1ANOVA[2, 1])
    fm1ANOVA[2, 5] <- 1 - pf(as.numeric(fm1ANOVA[2, 4]), fm1ANOVA[2, 
        1], fm1ANOVA[5, 1])
    class(fm1ANOVA) <- c("anova", "data.frame")
    return(list(anova = fm1ANOVA))

 }

YieldANOVA2 <- add_anova1(
      .data = df1
    , .y    = Y
    , .rep  = R
    , .gen  = G
    , .env  = E
  )
```

-checking with the output generated using 'ge_data' without changing the column names

```
all.equal(YieldANOVA, YieldANOVA2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Similarly `stab_reg` could be changed

Comment: Thanks @akrun for useful answer.